# Binding multiple variables to copies in BenchmarkTools.jl setup

Tags: julia

I am trying to use the `@benchmarkable` macro from `BenchmarkTools.jl`. In the [package documentaton](https://juliaci.github.io/BenchmarkTools.jl/stable/manual/#Setup-and-teardown-phases) they explain how to pass `setup` expressions to `@benchmark` and `@benchmarkable`. They also explain that this can be used for in-place/mutating functions in order to bind copies of the input variables.

I am not sure, however, how to use the `setup` expression to copy multiple variables at the same time.

For example, imagine I want to benchmark the following function (the actual function is irrelevant):

```
function my_function!(x, y)
    deleteat!(x, y .== 0)
    deleteat!(y, y .== 0)
    x .= x .* 2
end
```

With the following inputs:

```
using BenchmarkTools

a = collect(1:30)
b = rand(0:5, 30)
```

I would like to perform the benchmark by binding a copy of `a` and `b` to variables `y` and `z` respectively.

```
t = @benchmarkable my_function!(m, n) setup=(m = copy($a), n = copy($b)) evals = 30

run(t)
```

However, running the previous code returns the following error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: m not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup` requires a block of code so:

```
t =  @benchmarkable my_function!(m, n) setup=begin; m = copy($a); n = copy($b);end  evals = 30
```

Now you can run it:

```
julia> run(t)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 30 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  173.333 ns … 131.320 μs  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 99.33%
 Time  (median):     210.000 ns               ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   251.470 ns ±   1.315 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  5.19% ±  0.99%

  ▂█ ▁
  ██▇█▅▇█▅▆▃▃▃▃▃▃▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▂▁▁▁▂▁▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▂▂▂▂▂▂ ▃
  173 ns           Histogram: frequency by time          807 ns <
```